# WSL Adapter keeps changing settings

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I installed WSL 2  with an Ubuntu server on my organizations laptop. In order to get connectivity, I changed the adapter settings on my Windows 10 machine for IPv4 and IPv6 to DHCP instead of a static IP and it works.

After a while, the adapter seems to reset to a static IP after I drop from my VPN or if I loose internet connectivity. Is there a way to permanently set the windows adapter for WSL to DHCP settings?

Comment: This in no way shape or form answers your question but might help narrow your focus.  WSL (or WSL2) have nothing to do with the distro you have chosen to install. So "WSL2 for Ubuntu" isn't actually a thing.  The problem you are trying to solve has everything to do with WSL and nothing to do with Ubuntu.  I almost guarantee that 100% of this will be solved from "the windows side".

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest using DHCP on the WSL interface in windows as the solution.

However if it works for you, then my suggestion would be to enable "dhcp and static ip coexistence"
One simple command in an admin cmd prompt.  This enabled the interface to get an ip from DHCP even if a static ip is set.  This would be the best way to avoid your issue, when wsl runs network setup and adds the static ip.

```
netsh int ipv4 set interface "vEthernet (WSL)" dhcpstaticipcoexistence=enabled
```

Comment: powershell or ubuntu did not recognize that command

Comment: sorry typo, fixed now, netsh is the command.